# How to declare missing if more than X values are missing?

Tags: r, sum, average

Let's say I want to take the average (AVG) of 5 scores for assignments [X1 X2 X3 X4 X5]. How do I dictate the AVG to be missing if 2 OR MORE scores are missing? So if any 2 or more from [X1...X5] are missing then it lists AVG as missing or N/A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a function like the one below:

```
scorefunc <- function(x) {
  #if the total number of the missing is more than 1 return missing
  #else return the average value
  if(sum(is.na(x)) > 1) return(NA) else(return(mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)))
}
```

Then for testing:

```
#two example vectors 
vec1 <- c(1,5,6,7,NA)
vec2 <- c(NA, NA, 4, 1, 5)

#> scorefunc(vec1)
#[1] 4.75
#> scorefunc(vec2)
#[1] NA
```